# Managing passwords for disparate automated services?

Tags: password-protection

I've got a lot of automated services that need passwords to various resources.  databases, servers, and so forth.

My question is, what's the best way to secure these passwords while also allowing the applications to retrieve them in a secure manner?

The current idea is a web API they can query to grab the passwords.  They would pass in an authtoken and a key and get back the associated password.

The authtoken gets checked for validity (and permissions) before handing back the password.

My concern is how to verify further that the application is who they say they are outside of just having the authtoken.

Unfortunately I'm not working with an AD Domain, so that's out of the picture.

How have other people solved this problem?

In case it wasn't clear, if I don't have an AD Domain available I certainly don't have the ability to ship hardware modules to every datacenter that this is going to be implemented.

I apologize if that seems redundant, but it seems context gets lost on some folks.

Comment: The best way is a [Hardware security module (HSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).

Comment: Unfortunately, not an option.  I know I'll never make it 100% secure, I'm just looking for solutions that would be more secure than what I'm looking at doing now.

Comment: Oh I thought you asked for the best way.

Comment: Do I really need to edit my post to explain I'm looking for the best way that's feasible for me to implement?

Comment: Well I am merely pointing out that "the best x" does pretty poor as an SO question. because we simply cannot know what is and isn't feasible for you.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, do I really need to edit my post to explain I'm looking for the best way that's feasible for me to implement?

Comment: yes you should explain what's feasible and what's not for you.

Comment: I've updated with the necessary edit.  Now hopefully we can move on from this silly conversation.